# Is $H$ a subgroup?

Tags: abstract-algebra

For fixed $a,b$ in $S_n$ let $H=\{a^ib^j \mid i,j \text{ integers} \}$. Is $H\le S_n$?

Comment: What are your thoughts on the problem? Without knowing what you have tried and where you are stuck, you may not receive the help you would like, and the question is likely to be closed.

Answer (score 3):

The smallest counterexample is $n=3$, $a=(12)$, and $b=(13)$.

Comment: You beat me. Of course $2\cdot 3>2^2$ is just as as good as my $3\cdot 5>3^2$.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen But you answered first (by 9 seconds, if I remember correctly).  I wasn't thinking about using the orders of the groups, just trying to get a situation where $ba$ isn't in the alleged subgroup.

Answer (score 2):

This is not true. Consider $n=5$, $a=(1\,2\,3)$, $b=(3\,4\,5)$.
Then $H$ has at most $9$ elements and contains the element $ab=(1\,2\,3\,4\,5)$ of order $5$ as well as $a$ of order $3$, hence must have at least $15$ elements to be a group.